# ¿Cómo puedo crear una plantilla de un proyecto de c# con determinadas referencias?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Quisiera saber de que manera puedo crear una platilla de un proyecto en C# donde las referencias de mi proyecto se mantenga cuando cree un nuevo proyecto usando esta plantilla. Por cierto uso **Visual Studio 2015** y mi proyecto es una librería de clases de c#

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es como un desarrollo en capas? en donde tienes 3 proyectos, por asi decirlo(capa de datos, presentacion ,logica) en una misma solucion?

Comment: No, lo que quiero es crear un proyecto donde tenga clases y referencias a ensamblados externos a mi aplicación y crear de todo esto una plantilla para facilitarme el trabajo a la hora de crear proyectos similares. Y no tener que estar copiando y pegando.

Answer (score 1):

Para este propósito debe editar el archivo de plantilla VS en cada uno para eliminar el hecho de que no agregan automáticamente referencias a los ensamblados System, System.Data y / o System.Xml.

**2005:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\1033\Class.zip
```

**2008:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip
```

**2010:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip
```

A partir de Visual Studio 2012, las plantillas no están comprimidas, por lo que puede editar cada plantilla  `.cs` en cada carpeta correspondiente directamente.

**2012:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs
```

**2013:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs
```

**2015:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs
```

**2017**
VS 2017 cambia la ubicación del directorio y ahora depende de su edición (Profesional / Empresa / etc.). Entonces, para la edición Enterprise:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs
```

**2019**
La ubicación de VS 2019 es similar a 2017. Entonces, para la edición Enterprise:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs
```

**Notas**

> Tenga en cuenta que las actualizaciones de Service Pack borrarán su
>   caché, así que asegúrese de hacer una copia de seguridad para poder
>   volver a colocarla

**Ediciones Express**

En las ediciones Express, tendrá que buscar en el subdirectorio `WDExpress` dentro de la carpeta `IDE`, por ejemplo, VS 2015 Express:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs
```

**Otros idiomas**

Si no usa la versión en inglés de Visual Studio, es posible que la carpeta `1033` no exista, sino un número diferente que represente su idioma. Por ejemplo, está `1031` Etc...

**Referencia:** [How do I edit the Visual Studio templates for new C# class/interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2072717/8933039)

**Otros enlaces de Interés:**

- [How to modify the default new class template for C# in Visual Studio 2008 or 2010?](https://www.rhyous.com/2010/02/17/how-to-modify-the-default-new-class-template-in-visual-studio-2008/)
- [Change Class template in Visual Studio 2010](https://locktar.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/change-class-template-in-visual-studio-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes tu proyecto de biblioteca de clases creada, al compilarlo lo que genera es un .DLL, entonces cuando crees otro proyecto tienes que agregar una refencia a esa DLL, ejemplo: 
Instrucciones
1
Haz clic en el botón "Proyecto" del menú principal de Visual Studio .NET. En este menú, selecciona "Agregar referencia" de la lista.

2
Haz clic en la opción "Explorar" y navega hasta la ubicación del archivo DLL. Selecciónalo y presiona el botón "OK".

3
Inserta el espacio de nombres dentro del archivo de código de Visual Studio .NET. Para ocupar las clases de un DLL se requiere el comando "Using" en C#, mientras que el comando necesario para Visual Basic es "Import" (Importar). El código siguiente se requiere en la parte superior de cualquier archivo de código que ocupe el DLL: Using NombreDeMiDLL para C# y Import NombreDeMiDLL en vb.net.

4
Verifica el vínculo instanciando una clase del DLL importado. Una manera sencilla de verificar si el archivo fue importado es instanciar la clase encontrando su Intellisense. Por ejemplo, si el DLL contiene la clase "MiClase", al teclear su nombre en el área de trabajo de Visual Studio se creará una ventana emergente de Intellisense que mostrará la clase y sus métodos y propiedades asociados. Si la clase se encuentra en la lista, debes crear una instancia usando la sintaxis siguiente: MiClase mc = new MiClase();

Comment: Amigo todo eso que has explicado se hacerlo, si lees bien mi pregunta lo que quiero es realizar una plantilla de mi proyecto donde ya vengan incluidas como referencias varias dlls que ya habia importado. De esta manera cada vez que quiera hacer un proyecto similar no tenga que hacer los siguientes pasos. Proyecto -> Nuevo -> C# -> Mi Plantilla , ya despues que se creo el proyecto, ir a Referencias -> Agregar Referencia -> Seleccionar los archivos -> Aceptar, es muy engorroso