# ¿Cómo usar referencias de proyectos automáticas como rutas de ensamblaje?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Les planteo el escenario, tengo un proyecto de `Visual Studio C# 2010` que a su vez consta de 4 proyectos más que son los siguientes:

**Partes principales:**

- Principal (Correspondiente al proyecto base)
- Funciones_Metodos (Es una biblioteca de clases)

**Módulos:**

- Módulo 1
- Módulo 2
- Módulo 3

Ejemplo Gráfico:

[image: ejemplo proyecto de visual studio - 2010]

> **Como se puede observar cada `Módulo` tiene como referencia agregada la biblioteca de clases `Funciones_Metodos`** ya que esta contiene una clase llamada `Funciones` que como su nombre lo indica son Funciones y Métodos que generales para ser usados en todos los módulos; El proyecto `Principal` tiene como referencia agregada también la biblioteca de clases.

En cualquiera de esos proyectos mencionados, al momento de crear un nuevo:

- Form
- UserControl
- Class

**Cómo puedo agregar el ensamblado `using Funciones;`  automáticamente?**

**Ejemplo:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Funciones; //AGREGAR ESTO AUTOMATICAMENTE

namespace Principal
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Encontré aquí una pregunta similar: [¿Cómo puedo crear una plantilla de un proyecto de c# con determinadas referencias?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/97962/69447) pero no tiene la respuesta a lo que busco, para realizar este proceso de forma automática.

**Nota:** si el título de mi pregunta no esta bien elaborado favor corregirme, no supe como elaborar un título mas adecuado.

Comment: Hay una excelente respuesta en ingles... ahora la traduzco

Comment: @gbianchi De acuerdo, estoy a espera :)

Comment: creo que con #if puedes hacer directivas que impriman o ignoren directamente codigo dependiendo de tu ambiente de compilacion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990919/if-preprocessor-directive-for-directives-other-than-debug

Comment: @Mike me parece que ha interpretado mal mi pregunta, no es eso lo que busco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomando como base la respuesta de @gbianchi, coloco los pasos a seguir para que esto funcione de manera adecuada:

1- Dirigirse al directorio correspondiente a la versión de su Visual Studio (En mi Caso VS-2010):

- **ItemTemplates:**

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip

- **ItemTemplatesCache:**

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip

2- Preferiblemente copiar el archivo `Class.zip` en el escritorio y descomprimir.

3- Editar ambos archivos, puede ser con el editor de texto si desea, y agregar el `using` o libreria que necesique que le muestre por defecto. en mi caso agregué `using Funciones;`

3- Empaquetar nuevamente el `Class.zip` y pegarlo en la ruta correspondiente y sobreercribir el archivo existente.

4- Dirigirse a esta otra ruta:

> C:\Users\TuUsuario\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\

5- Eliminar la carpeta llamada `ItemTemplatesCache_{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` que se encuentra en la ruta especificada en el paso Nro. 4.

6- Abra un símbolo del sistema como administrador

7- En la ventana de comando dirigase a la ruta:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
```

8- Ejecute este comando:

```
devenv.exe /installvstemplates
```

Esto sería todo, con esto debe funcionar perfectamente.

Answer (score 1):

> Esta respuesta es una traducción de [How do I edit the Visual Studio
> templates for new C#
> class/interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072687/how-do-i-edit-the-visual-studio-templates-for-new-c-sharp-class-interface)

Extraer, editar y recomprimir. Las rutas son para los templates de clases, pero las interfaces estan en la misma carpeta.

Querras editar cada template para, por ejemplo, que no agregue determinadas referencias, o como en tu caso, para que agregue otras referencias.

#### 2005:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\1033\Class.zip

#### 2008:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip

#### 2010:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip

Despues de VS 2012, los template no esta mas comprimidos, por lo que hay que modificar cada .cs en sus carpetas directamente

#### 2012:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs

#### 2013:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs

#### 2015:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs

#### 2017

VS 2017 cambio las carpetas que usa, asi que ahora depende de la edición que estes usando que carpeta corresponde. Por ejemplo para la version enterprise seria:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs

## Notes

#### Ediciones Express

En la Edición express, vas a tener que buscar la carpeta WDExpress dentro de la carpeta IDE. Por ejemplo en VS 2015 Express

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs

#### Otros lenguajes

Si VS esta configurado en otro idioma, puede que la carpeta 1033 no exista, pero existe otro número diferente representado el lenguaje.

### Más notas:

- Hay que tener cuidado que las clases no esten en un cache, es ese caso tambien que hay que cambiarlas en ItemTemplatesCache
- Se puede forzar a VS a leer los template haciendo devenv /setup
- Si los templates estan en un zip, no hacer una copia del zip, porque VS puede tratar de cargar esa copia
- Hacer un backup de los template, VS puede borrarlos al hacer una actualización.

Comment: En mi caso toca este 2010: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip` pero no me queda claro como edito esa plantilla  para indicarle que debe agregar `using Funciones;`, estoy perdido en eso...

Comment: Abre el zip, y modifica la plantailla del archivo que queres.. en tu caso el de clases...

Comment: Esto contiene la clase en el zip: `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;
using Funciones;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
 class $safeitemrootname$
 {
 }
}`  Le he agregado `using Funciones;`  pero al momento de probarlo no agrega dicha referencia, que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Fijate que tenes que verificar el cache, tenes que reiniciar.. no es tan trivial como parece.. y ademas.. volviste a empaquetar todo en el zip?

Comment: _volviste a empaquetar todo en el zip?_ Si lo hice, me faltaría reiniciar para poder, probar voy a eso, espera

Comment: y fijate que no este en el cache

Comment: Ya he modificado la clase en ambas rutas: `ItemTemplates` y `ItemTemplatesCache` y he reiniciado y aun no funciona :(,  me parece que al editar la clase no basta con solo colocar `using funciones;` porque no sabe de donde proviene esa linea aunque la tenga para que la compile en esa clase VS